# How to estimate the confidence interval using sample average and sample size ONLY?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation

Suppose there is a population, with goods and bads. The bad rate of the population(=bads/(bads+goods)) is of course unknown.

Now, I have a sample of $N$ from the population and I know the bad rate of this sample as $b$. The question is can I calculate the confidence interval based on $N$ and $b$ ONLY? In other words, can I calculate the confidence interval $x$ such that with, say, 95% confidence the population bad rate falls in $[\text{range}_1,\text{range}_2]$, where $\text{range}_1$ will be $b-x$ and $\text{range}_2$ will be $b+x$.

Comment: Under random sampling, yes; this is simply a confidence interval for a binomial proportion, with the usual caveats about the assumptions of and interpretation of confidence intervals.

Comment: As long as $np(1-p)$ is not small (bigger than 10 is usually plenty), you can use the normal interval described [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30281/sample-size-for-binomial-confidence-interval/30306#30306). If the $n$ is small and $p$ is very near 0 or 1, you may need to consider one of the [other binomial approximate confidence intervals](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28316/confidence-interval-for-a-proportion-when-sample-proportion-is-almost-1-or-0). Many other posts here cover aspects of CIs for binomial proportions; the search bar turns many up.

Comment: Further examples of previous posts on this topic: [e.g. 1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/confidence-interval-for-bernoulli-sampling), [e.g. 2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/confidence-interval-for-bernoulli-sampling)

Comment: Just as a side note - if you want to control your confidence level, then the size of the interval also depends on that.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Glen_b said. Under random sampling the confidence interval for a binomial proportion can be easily calculated with, e.g., using the normal approximation. The formula can be found from Wikipedia, among other sources (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

As an example, the 95% confidence interval for a sample of 1000 with the proportion of bad of 0.5, the confidence interval would be from 0.5-sqrt((1/1000)*0.5*0.5)*1.96 to 0.5+sqrt((1/1000)*0.5*0.5)*1.96. In other words, in this case the 95% confidence interval would be 0.469-0.530.